# Hide the Progress of X/Y format while downloading and showing in Dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i have implemented the downloading of file and show the progress into a dialog. Everything is working absolutely fine. Now while implementing the things i have implemented the dialog code in following manner:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case progress_bar_type: // we set this to 0
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Attachment. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            return pDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Calculating and showing percentage with this below code:

```
publishProgress((int) ((total * 100) / filelength));
```

My AsyncTask methods:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {

            showDialog(progress_bar_type);
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            pDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }
```

Now my dialog is showing a downloading progress and also showing the progress update in **%** as well as in **30/100** i.e X/Y format.

Now i want only percentage to be shown and not the X/Y format as similar to gmail downloading dialog in android.

Comment: Added code does not show any X/Y or % for progress. Add correct code here...

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
float downloadedSize = 0, totalSize = 0, per = 0, fdownloadedSize = 0,
        ftotalSize = 0;

NumberFormat numberFormat;

pDialog.setProgress((int) downloadedSize);
            numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
            per = (downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100;
            fdownloadedSize = downloadedSize / (1024 * 1024);
            ftotalSize = totalSize / (1024 * 1024);
            // update the progressbar //
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tvDownloadingPercent.setText("Downloaded "
                            + numberFormat.format(fdownloadedSize)
                            + "MB / " + numberFormat.format(ftotalSize)
                            + "MB (" + numberFormat.format(per) + "%)");


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just added

```
pDialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
```

to the dialog and it works.